# How to delete excel file by the content in java

Tags: java, excel, delete-file

I have some excel files, and I want to delete it by the content.
As example, there is one file that is crashed and has no content. How can I delete that file with java using `byte[]`?

Answer (score 0):

CSV Parser to pase file.

```
package com.epox.cmc.core.util;

import java.util.*;


/**
 * @author SMehta
 * 
 */
public class CSVParser {


    public static final char DEFAULT_SEP = ',';

    /** Construct a CSV parser, with the default separator (`,'). */
    public CSVParser() {
        this(DEFAULT_SEP);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a CSV parser with a given separator.
     * 
     * @param sep
     *            The single char for the separator (not a list of separator
     *            characters)
     */
    public CSVParser(char sep) {
        fieldSep = sep;
    }

    /** The fields in the current String */
    protected List list = new ArrayList();

    /** the separator char for this parser */
    protected char fieldSep;

    /**
     * parse: break the input String into fields
     * 
     * @return java.util.Iterator containing each field from the original as a
     *         String, in order.
     */
    public List parse(String line) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        list.clear(); // recycle to initial state
        int i = 0;

        if (line.length() == 0) {
            list.add(line);
            return list;
        }

        do {
            sb.setLength(0);
            if (i < line.length() && line.charAt(i) == '"')
                i = advQuoted(line, sb, ++i); // skip quote
            else
                i = advPlain(line, sb, i);
            list.add(sb.toString());        
            i++;
        } while (i < line.length());

        return list;
    }

    /** advQuoted: quoted field; return index of next separator */
    protected int advQuoted(String s, StringBuffer sb, int i) {
        int j;
        int len = s.length();
        for (j = i; j < len; j++) {
            if (s.charAt(j) == '"' && j + 1 < len) {
                if (s.charAt(j + 1) == '"') {
                    j++; // skip escape char
                } else if (s.charAt(j + 1) == fieldSep) { //next delimeter
                    j++; // skip end quotes
                    break;
                }
            } else if (s.charAt(j) == '"' && j + 1 == len) { // end quotes at
                                                             // end of line
                break; //done
            }
            sb.append(s.charAt(j)); // regular character.
        }
        return j;
    }

    /** advPlain: unquoted field; return index of next separator */
    protected int advPlain(String s, StringBuffer sb, int i) {
        int j;

        j = s.indexOf(fieldSep, i); // look for separator

        if (j == -1) { // none found
            sb.append(s.substring(i));
            return s.length();
        } else {
            sb.append(s.substring(i, j));
            return j;
        }
    }

}
```

Convert byte[] to List> .

```
private List<List<String>> parseFile(byte[] csvFileData) throws  Exception {

        List<List<String>> data;
        Reader targetReader =  null;
        CSVParser csvParser = null;

        try {
            CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT;
            targetReader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(csvFileData));
            csvParser = new CSVParser(new BufferedReader(targetReader),csvFormat);

            List<CSVRecord> records = csvParser.getRecords();
            data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : records) {
                Iterator<String> iterator = csvRecord.iterator();
                List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String column = iterator.next();
                    row.add(column);
                }
                data.add(row);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {

            if(targetReader != null)
                targetReader.close();

            if(csvParser != null)
                csvParser.close();
        }


        return data;
    }
```

Now check Size of the list and delete the file based on the size